# ios developer certificate private key

Tags: iphone, ios

my certificate was about to expire, so i revoked the old one from the ios provisioning portal and created a new one with xcode (everything worked automatically).
After that i set the provisioning profiles to the new certificate within the ios provisioning portal and pressed the "renew" button within the organizer.

Now i recognized that if i want to use some old ipa (wich was signed with a different certificate) i cannot install it on the iphone (getting some message like signature is invalid or so). I've read that when you create a new certificate you should use the old private key. Unfortunally i dont know where the old private key is located (since i'm new at this project).

Just for clarification: if i would create the new certificate with the old private key, will the old ipa work or do i still have to create a new one with the new certificate signed.

And will there any complications when i decide to update my app within the apple store?

thx for help,

kuku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the certificate will not complicate any updates to AppStore apps, just be sure that the  BundleID is the same. ( You can't send in a update if the bundle id is not the same).

I've been updating one app for 4 years now and have even switched machines in those years, I have create many different certificates for the same account and update the apps many times.

Comment: Yes, if lost one machine and had to restart on a new machine. No I work in a team an we all share the same keys and I create a new one every year.

Comment: Do you know if i used the old private key for the new certificate, would old ipa files still be working (which are signed with the old certificate but same private key)

Comment: but i could just install the new provisioning profile to the device or am i missing something .. sorry but i'm kinda new to this stuff.